# .NET 6 how to call configure method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have in .net 5 a `Configure` method which is called by runtime

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IEventBusSubscriber bus){}
```

In the migration guide it is shown an example how to call it

```
var app = builder.Build();
startup.Configure(app, app.Environment);
```

I can pass to this method an `app` and `env`  because I have an `app` instance, but what to do with `IEventBusSubscriber`?

Perhaps I could use `app.Services.GetService(typeof(IEventBusSubscriber)) as IEventBusSubscriber`
but it gives me possible null reference which I can avoid, but is it the right way to do it?

Comment: I'd use the `app.Services.GetRequiredService<IEventBusSubscriber>()` extension method. This will return non-null (or throw if not configured).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I configure my event bus in ASP.NET Core 6 - Migration to .NET 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71099106/how-can-i-configure-my-event-bus-in-asp-net-core-6-migration-to-net-6)